# Facing issue in UIPageControl in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app in Swift. I am trying to run the app and get this error for a firstViewController.hidePageControl() from SecondViewController. Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks.

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

**FirstViewController.swift**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

     @IBOutlet var pageControl : UIPageControl!

     func hidePageControl() {

         self.pageControl.hidden = true
     }
}
```

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

     var firstViewController : FirstViewController!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         firstViewController.hidePageControl()
     }

}
```

Comment: Unless you assign some value to the firstViewController property, it *is* nil.

Comment: You need to provide more information how these two view controllers are connected. The error occurred because Swift doesn't allow optional type to be nil when accessing it. In this case, it's because either or both of firstViewController.pageControl or secondViewController.firstViewController is nil. Read more about optional type in the Apple's Swift book if you haven't read it yet.